Looking for examples of non-affine morphisms
I am looking for examples of non-affine morphisms between quasi-projective varieties over an algebraically closed field (classical geometric setting). After looking for quite a while now, I only came up with rather boring examples though:

Open immersions given by non-affine open subsets of affine varieties, like $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\} \to \mathbb{A}^2$
Constant maps from projective varieties into affine varieties, like $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{A}^1$
Locally constant maps from disjoint unions of projective varieties into an affine variety, like $\mathbb{P}^1 \sqcup \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{A}^1$

I'd really like to see a more exciting example.
More precise question: Are there non-affine non-constant morphisms between irreducible projective varieties?

I guess there is $\mathbb{P}^n \to Spec(K)$, but this is not the excitment you are looking for.

@CaptainLama: You are right. I changed "dominant" to "non-constant".

How about the product projection from a Cartesian product of two projective varieties?

@ZhenLin This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Do you like to turn your comment into an answer? (otherwise I would do so)

Let $V$ be a (irreducible) projective variety of dimension $\ge 1$ and let $W$ be any (irreducible) projective variety.
Then $V \times W$ is also a (irreducible) projective variety (by the Segre embedding) and the product projection $V \times W \to W$ is not affine: after all, its fibres are $V$, which is by hypothesis not affine.

Generalizing Zhen Lin's anwer: Let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism between projective (or more generally proper) varieties and suppose that $\mathrm{dim}(X)>\mathrm{dim}(Y)$. Then $f$ is not affine.
Any morphism between proper varieties is proper. A proper affine morphism is finite. (stacks 01WN) A finite (or more generally integral morphism) between schemes $X \to Y$ induces an inequality of dimensions (stacks 0ECG) $\mathrm{dim} X \leq \mathrm{dim} Y$, which contradicts the assumption.
